# TextView update crashes application

Tags: android, textview

This has been discussed many times before, but it is still a real pain for me.

PROBLEM: App crashes whenever I try to update text it TextView

CONTEXT: Im using bluetooth app with multi threads. The "listening" thread (ConnectedThread) sends Handler whenever new message is obtained. This handler is then resolved in main Activity, where the TextView is initialized.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED/CHECKED SO FAR:

1. I think I am not updating TextView from different activity/thread
2. the TextView is initialized after setContentView(R.layout.main); (well, in other post, this was causing the trouble)

CODE: (in short)

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
 public class BluetoothActivity extends Activity {

 private TextView mDisplay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        .....
        ..
    }


    private void setupApp() {

        // Initialize the BluetoothService to perform bluetooth connections
        // This is where the Handler is passed to "ConnectedThread" (it is part of    
           mService)
        mService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler); 
    }


    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

            ......

            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Received: " + readMessage);

                mDisplay.setText(readMessage); <----- THIS IS THE ISSUE

                break;
                .......
                ....
            }
        }
    };
```

CONNECTED THREAD

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    ...... 

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Primarily this was the function respossible for showing incoming messages

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Received: " + readMessage,   
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I forgot to set mDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Display);